# Definitions for Project, Session, Workspace, Perspective,

Tags: doom

Is there a nice definition list for the following concepts and more?

- project (projectile vs. emacs?)
- session (just doom emacs?)
- workspace (just doom emacs?)
- perspective
- lsp-session
- lsp-workspace
- ...

I know, this depends on configuration and used packages. But then there are very popular packages which provide these concepts and other packages which have their own definitions. But that's why it would be very helpful to have an overview and see the conflicts.

It would be nice to also see the relationships between these concepts. For example between a project and lsp-session, project and workspace,...